# if else logic with empty dates

Tags: python, date, pandas, datetime, if-statement

I'm trying to write a function that returns some dates in python.

```
def set_deadline(row):
    if row["date1"] is not None:
        return row["date1"]+ relativedelta(days=+90)
    else:
        return None
```

Since some of the records have the `date1` field missing (NaT), the error

> bad month number nan; must be 1-12

shows up why I try to use this function on my dataframe.  How can I change the function so that the deadline would be Nan or None if the date1 field is missing?

I also tried just to define the deadline field by doing the following:

```
df['Deadline']= df['date1']+ relativedelta(days=+90)
```

but I got the error

> incompatible type [object] for a datetime/timedelta operation

Comment: have you tried converting the dataframe to datetime time and then adding the relativedelta?

Comment: You can use np.isnan() method to check whether the data is not NaN.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use for python exceptions.  You did not give the exact exception you are seeing, but you should limit this to just that exception.

```
def set_deadline(row):
    try:
        return row["date1"] + relativedelta(days=90)
    except:
        return row["date1"]
```